Code Developing processing with aiken-lang smart contract
Question-1.Are my code in git repo?
Answer: yes it is the link: https://github.com/Plutus-art/Aiken-Research

The official Aiken-lang GitHub repository serves as the primary
source for the Aiken programming language, which is designed for
developing smart contracts on the Cardano blockchain. Here's an
overview of what you might find in the repository:
##1. Source Code Compiler: The core compiler for the Aiken language, which translates Aiken code into Plutus Core, the smart contract
language used by Cardano. Standard Library: A collection of reusable
functions, data types, and modules that provide essential
functionality for developers.
##2. Documentation Getting Started Guide: Instructions on how to install Aiken, set up the development environment, and write your
first smart contract. Language Reference: Detailed descriptions of
Aiken's syntax, semantics, and built-in functions, helping developers
understand how to effectively use the language.
##3. Examples and Tutorials Sample Contracts: Example smart contracts that demonstrate various features and functionalities of Aiken, such
as token contracts, NFT minting, and decentralized applications
(dApps). Tutorials: Step-by-step guides that walk developers through
the process of building specific types of applications or using
particular Aiken features.
##4. Testing and Tools Testing Framework: Tools and libraries for writing and running tests for Aiken contracts, ensuring they function
as expected. Deployment Scripts: Scripts that facilitate the
deployment of Aiken contracts to the Cardano blockchain, making the
process smoother for developers.
##5. Community Contributions Issue Tracking: A space for users to report bugs, request features, or ask questions, fostering community
engagement. Pull Requests: Contributions from the community that can
enhance the Aiken language, adding new features or fixing issues.
##6. Release Notes Changelog: Information about updates, improvements, and new features introduced in different versions of Aiken, allowing
developers to stay informed about the latest changes.
##7. License Information Open Source License: Details about the licensing under which Aiken is released, usually allowing developers
to use, modify, and distribute the software within the terms of the
license.
##2. are we try to process new code experiment with new functions and features of aiken-lang smart contract? Answer Yes here is some  o
develop smart contracts using Aiken for the Cardano blockchain, you
need to understand the necessary tools, features, and functions.
Here's a detailed overview:
Necessary Requirements Development Environment
Aiken Compiler: Install the Aiken compiler, which is used to compile
your Aiken code into Plutus Core (the underlying language for Cardano
smart contracts). Text Editor or IDE: Use a code editor like Visual
Studio Code, which supports Aiken syntax highlighting and extensions
for development. Cardano Wallet and Node
Cardano Wallet: Set up a Cardano wallet to manage your funds and
interact with the blockchain. Node Access: You might want to run your
own Cardano node or use a third-party service to interact with the
Cardano blockchain for deploying and testing contracts. Familiarity
with Blockchain Concepts
Understand blockchain fundamentals, especially related to UTXOs
(Unspent Transaction Outputs) and how Cardano handles transactions
and state. Aiken Language Syntax
Familiarize yourself with the Aiken syntax and semantics, which
includes types, functions, and contract structure. Testing Framework
Use testing frameworks available for Aiken to write and run tests for
your contracts, ensuring correctness before deployment. Key Features
of Aiken Strong Typing System
Aiken's type system helps catch errors at compile time, improving the
reliability of smart contracts. Functional Programming Paradigm
Aiken is designed around functional programming principles, enabling
concise and clear code structure. Pattern Matching
Simplified handling of complex data structures, making it easier to
write robust and maintainable code. Concurrency Support
Manage multiple operations efficiently, which is crucial for dApps
that require responsiveness. Interoperability with Cardano
Aiken facilitates easy integration with Cardano's native tokens and
on-chain data, enhancing your contracts' capabilities. New Features
and Functions (Hypothetical) Enhanced Data Structures
Future versions might introduce more complex data types (e.g.,
tuples, lists) for better modeling of real-world entities. Improved
Error Handling
Advanced error handling mechanisms could be added, such as custom
exceptions or logging features for better debugging. In-built
Libraries
Libraries for common functionalities (like cryptographic operations,
date-time handling, etc.) could simplify development. Deployment
Tools
Enhanced tooling for easier deployment and migration of contracts,
including automated scripts and templates. User Interface Components
Potential integration with frontend frameworks or libraries to build
user interfaces that interact with Aiken contracts directly. Better
Integration with Cardano Ecosystem
Features that facilitate integration with other Cardano projects,
such as oracles or cross-chain interactions.
3. Invalid Type Error
    entrypoint main(x: Int) -> Bool {
        x + "string"  -- Invalid operation between Int and String
    } } ```

**Error:**

```shell Error: Invalid operand types for `+` (Int, String) ```

**Solution:**   Fix the type mismatch by removing the string concatenation.

```aiken contract FixedContract {
    entrypoint main(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
        x + y
    } } ```

---


Conditional_logic.ak

contract ConditionalContract {
    entrypoint main(x: Int) -> Bool {
        if x > 10 {
            True
        } else {
            False
        }
    } } no2:

test_Conditional_logic.ak


test ConditionalTest {
    assert_eq!(ConditionalContract::main(11), True)
    assert_eq!(ConditionalContract::main(5), False) } no:3 simple.ak

contract Simple {
    entrypoint main() -> Bool {
        True
    } } ```

Test_simple.ak

test SimpleTest {
    assert_eq!(Simple::main(), True) }

the rest you can find on github repo Development Code
Process: https://github.com/Plutus-art/Aiken-Research




Question-2: What is the New on Aiken-lang?
Answer: here are some recent developments and features that may be included in

Aiken-lang:

Language Enhancements Improved Syntax and Features: Ongoing updates may include new language constructs, syntactic sugar, and
features that enhance developer experience and code readability.

Standard Library Updates Expanded Functions: New utility functions and data structures might be added to the standard library, making it
easier to implement common patterns in smart contracts.

Improved Compiler Performance Optimization: Enhancements to the compiler that improve performance, error reporting, and code
optimization for better execution on the Cardano blockchain.

Documentation and Learning Resources Comprehensive Guides: Updates to official documentation, including more tutorials, code examples,
and best practices to help new developers get started and improve
their skills.

Testing and Tooling New Testing Frameworks: Introduction of better testing frameworks or tools that streamline the process of writing,
running, and managing tests for Aiken contracts.

Community Engagement Workshops and Webinars: Increased community outreach through educational events, workshops, or webinars to help
developers learn about Aiken and its capabilities.

Integration with Other Ecosystems Cross-Chain Functionality: Potential developments in interoperability with other blockchain
ecosystems, enabling Aiken contracts to interact with various
platforms.

User Feedback Incorporation Feature Requests: Regular updates based on community feedback, addressing user-requested features or
improvements.
Question-3. Can we create Dex-Swap System with aiken-lang smart contract?
Answer: Yes

here is some basic developing process for Dex swap in aiken
mint.ak
// native_token_minting.aiken
validator {   // Validates minting rules for the native token   fn
validate_minting(tx: Tx, minting_policy: PubKeyHash, amount: Value)
-> Bool {
let mint = tx.mint[0] // Access the first minting transaction
// Ensure that only the allowed policy can mint the token
let valid_minter = mint.policy == minting_policy

// Ensure the minting amount is positive
let valid_amount = mint.amount > 0

// Both conditions must be true for the mint to be valid
valid_minter && valid_amount   } }

parameter.ak
// native_token_parameters.aiken
// Define token parameters const TOKEN_POLICY: PubKeyHash =
"your_policy_id_here" const TOKEN_NAME: ByteArray =
"YourTokenName".as_bytes()
// Minting function, called when creating new tokens fn
mint_native_token(tx: Tx) -> Bool {   validate_minting(tx,
TOKEN_POLICY, 1000)  // Mint 1000 units of the token }
Minting_control.ak
// native_token_minting_control.aiken
validator {   // Validates that the minting transaction is signed by
the correct key   fn validate_minting_with_authorization(tx: Tx,
authorized_pubkey: PubKeyHash, minting_policy: PubKeyHash, amount:
Value) -> Bool {
let signer = tx.signatories[0]  // First signer of the transaction
// Ensure the signer is the authorized minter and validate the mint
let valid_signer = signer == authorized_pubkey
let valid_minting = validate_minting(tx, minting_policy, amount)

// Both conditions must be true for the minting to be valid
valid_signer && valid_minting   } }

native_token_burning.ak // native_token_burning.aiken
validator {   // Validates burning of the native token   fn
validate_burning(tx: Tx, burn_policy: PubKeyHash, amount: Value) ->
Bool {
let burn = tx.burn[0]  // Access the first burn transaction
// Ensure that only the allowed policy can burn the token
let valid_burner = burn.policy == burn_policy

// Ensure the burning amount is positive (burning should always be less than total supply)
let valid_amount = burn.amount > 0

// Both conditions must be true for the burn to be valid
valid_burner && valid_amount   }

Native_token_deploy.ak
// native_token_deploy.aiken
validator {   // Combines minting and burning logic into a single
smart contract   fn mint_or_burn(tx: Tx, authorized_pubkey:
PubKeyHash, policy: PubKeyHash, amount: Value) -> Bool {
let is_mint = tx.mint.len > 0
let is_burn = tx.burn.len > 0
if is_mint {
  validate_minting_with_authorization(tx, authorized_pubkey, policy, amount)
} else if is_burn {
  validate_burning(tx, policy, amount)
} else {
  // No valid mint or burn action detected
  false
}   } }



Question-4: Can we create NFT marketplace with aiken-lang smart contract?
answer:

marketplace.ak
contract NFTMarketplace {
// Data structures
record NFT {
id: Int,
owner: Address,
price: Int,
isListed: Bool,
auctionEndTime: Maybe(Time),
highestBid: Maybe<(Address, Int)>,
}
// Storage
storage nfts: Map<Int, NFT> = {}
storage stakingBalances: Map<Address, Int> = {}

// List NFT for sale
entrypoint listNFT(nftId: Int, price: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    // Check if the NFT exists and is owned by the caller
    if nft.owner != caller {
        abort("You do not own this NFT.")
    }

    // Update NFT to be listed
    nfts[nftId] = { nft with price = price, isListed = True }
}

// Delist NFT
entrypoint delistNFT(nftId: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    // Check if the NFT is listed and owned by the caller
    if !nft.isListed || nft.owner != caller {
        abort("Cannot delist this NFT.")
    }

    // Update NFT to be unlisted
    nfts[nftId] = { nft with isListed = False }
}

// Buy NFT
entrypoint buyNFT(nftId: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    // Check if NFT is listed and payment is correct
    if !nft.isListed || amount != nft.price {
        abort("Cannot buy this NFT.")
    }

    // Transfer NFT ownership
    nfts[nftId] = { nft with owner = caller, isListed = False }
}

// Start Auction
entrypoint startAuction(nftId: Int, duration: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    if nft.owner != caller {
        abort("You do not own this NFT.")
    }

    // Set auction parameters
    nfts[nftId] = { nft with auctionEndTime = Just(currentTime + duration), highestBid = Nothing }
}

// Place Bid
entrypoint bid(nftId: Int, bidAmount: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    // Check if auction is active
    if nft.auctionEndTime == Nothing || currentTime >= nft.auctionEndTime {
        abort("Auction is not active.")
    }

    // Check if bid is higher than the current highest bid
    let highestBid = nft.highestBid
    if highestBid != Nothing && bidAmount <= snd(highestBid) {
        abort("Bid must be higher than the current highest bid.")
    }

    // Update highest bid
    nfts[nftId] = { nft with highestBid = Just((caller, bidAmount)) }
}

// Claim NFT after auction ends
entrypoint claimNFT(nftId: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    // Check if auction has ended
    if nft.auctionEndTime == Nothing || currentTime < nft.auctionEndTime {
        abort("Auction has not ended yet.")
    }

    // Transfer NFT ownership to the highest bidder
    let highestBid = nft.highestBid
    if highestBid == Nothing {
        abort("No bids were placed.")
    }

    nfts[nftId] = { nft with owner = fst(highestBid), auctionEndTime = Nothing, highestBid = Nothing }
}

// Staking functionality
entrypoint stake(amount: Int) {
    // Update staking balances
    stakingBalances[caller] = (stakingBalances[caller] + amount)
}

entrypoint unstake(amount: Int) {
    // Check if caller has enough staked
    if stakingBalances[caller] < amount {
        abort("Not enough staked to unstake.")
    }

    // Update staking balances
    stakingBalances[caller] = (stakingBalances[caller] - amount)
} }

Here's a simplified version of an NFT marketplace smart contract in
Aiken-lang that includes features for listing, delisting, buying,
selling, auction bidding, and staking. This example focuses on the
structure and logic; in a real implementation, you'd need to handle
many additional aspects like security, error handling, and state
management.
NFT Marketplace Smart Contract in Aiken-lang aiken Copy code contract
NFTMarketplace {
// Data structures
record NFT {
id: Int,
owner: Address,
price: Int,
isListed: Bool,
auctionEndTime: Maybe(Time),
highestBid: Maybe<(Address, Int)>,
}
// Storage
storage nfts: Map<Int, NFT> = {}
storage stakingBalances: Map<Address, Int> = {}

// List NFT for sale
entrypoint listNFT(nftId: Int, price: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    // Check if the NFT exists and is owned by the caller
    if nft.owner != caller {
        abort("You do not own this NFT.")
    }

    // Update NFT to be listed
    nfts[nftId] = { nft with price = price, isListed = True }
}

// Delist NFT
entrypoint delistNFT(nftId: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    // Check if the NFT is listed and owned by the caller
    if !nft.isListed || nft.owner != caller {
        abort("Cannot delist this NFT.")
    }

    // Update NFT to be unlisted
    nfts[nftId] = { nft with isListed = False }
}

// Buy NFT
entrypoint buyNFT(nftId: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    // Check if NFT is listed and payment is correct
    if !nft.isListed || amount != nft.price {
        abort("Cannot buy this NFT.")
    }

    // Transfer NFT ownership
    nfts[nftId] = { nft with owner = caller, isListed = False }
}

// Start Auction
entrypoint startAuction(nftId: Int, duration: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    if nft.owner != caller {
        abort("You do not own this NFT.")
    }

    // Set auction parameters
    nfts[nftId] = { nft with auctionEndTime = Just(currentTime + duration), highestBid = Nothing }
}

// Place Bid
entrypoint bid(nftId: Int, bidAmount: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    // Check if auction is active
    if nft.auctionEndTime == Nothing || currentTime >= nft.auctionEndTime {
        abort("Auction is not active.")
    }

    // Check if bid is higher than the current highest bid
    let highestBid = nft.highestBid
    if highestBid != Nothing && bidAmount <= snd(highestBid) {
        abort("Bid must be higher than the current highest bid.")
    }

    // Update highest bid
    nfts[nftId] = { nft with highestBid = Just((caller, bidAmount)) }
}

// Claim NFT after auction ends
entrypoint claimNFT(nftId: Int) {
    let nft = nfts[nftId]

    // Check if auction has ended
    if nft.auctionEndTime == Nothing || currentTime < nft.auctionEndTime {
        abort("Auction has not ended yet.")
    }

    // Transfer NFT ownership to the highest bidder
    let highestBid = nft.highestBid
    if highestBid == Nothing {
        abort("No bids were placed.")
    }

    nfts[nftId] = { nft with owner = fst(highestBid), auctionEndTime = Nothing, highestBid = Nothing }
}

// Staking functionality
entrypoint stake(amount: Int) {
    // Update staking balances
    stakingBalances[caller] = (stakingBalances[caller] + amount)
}

entrypoint unstake(amount: Int) {
    // Check if caller has enough staked
    if stakingBalances[caller] < amount {
        abort("Not enough staked to unstake.")
    }

    // Update staking balances
    stakingBalances[caller] = (stakingBalances[caller] - amount)
} } Key Features Implemented Listing NFTs: Users can list their NFTs for sale with a specific price. Delisting NFTs: Users can remove

their NFTs from the marketplace. Buying NFTs: Users can buy listed
NFTs by sending the correct amount. Auction Management: Users can
start auctions, place bids, and claim NFTs after auctions end.
Staking: Users can stake and unstake tokens, allowing for potential
rewards in a full implementation.


Question-5.Can we create decentralized-applications with aiken lang smart contract?
Answer: Yes Here is  Some Example codes with aiken New Features

Certainly! Here are five example code snippets for potential
functions and features you might include in a decentralized
application (dApp) using Aiken-lang smart contracts. Each snippet
showcases a different functionality relevant to dApp development.
1. User Registration
registerUser(username: String) {
    // Check if username is unique
    if (usernames[username] != Nothing) {
        abort("Username already exists.")
    }
    // Register user
    usernames[username] = caller } ```

### 2. Voting Mechanism

```aiken // Voting feature for a simple governance dApp record Vote {
    proposalId: Int,
    voter: Address,
    choice: Bool, }

entrypoint castVote(proposalId: Int, choice: Bool) {
    // Ensure the voter has not voted yet
    if (votingRecords[caller][proposalId] != Nothing) {
        abort("You have already voted.")
    }
    // Record the vote
    votingRecords[caller][proposalId] = Just({ proposalId, caller, choice }) } ```

### 3. Token Transfer

```aiken // Function to transfer tokens between users entrypoint
transferTokens(to: Address, amount: Int) {
    let balance = tokenBalances[caller]

    // Ensure sufficient balance
    if (balance < amount) {
        abort("Insufficient balance.")
    }

    // Update balances
    tokenBalances[caller] = balance - amount
    tokenBalances[to] = (tokenBalances[to] + amount) } ```

### 4. Loyalty Rewards

```aiken // Reward users for transactions entrypoint
rewardUser(rewardAmount: Int) {
    // Check if user has made a transaction recently
    if (recentTransactions[caller] == Nothing) {
        abort("No recent transactions to reward.")
    }

    // Update reward balance
    rewardBalances[caller] = (rewardBalances[caller] + rewardAmount) } ```

### 5. NFT Minting

```aiken // Function to mint a new NFT entrypoint mintNFT(metadata:
String) {
    let newId = nextNftId

    // Create the NFT
    nfts[newId] = { id = newId, owner = caller, metadata = metadata, isMinted = True }
    nextNftId = nextNftId + 1 } ```



